# Create a template for product backlog items with predefined attached tasks

Tags: templates, azure-devops

in my org we would like to create a template for product backlogs items, that will include alos predefined list of tasks that will be assigned to each product backlog item created with this template.
For example:
Task for adding configuration and settings
Task for documentation
Task for E2E test, etc.

I could not identify an option to add tasks for a template, or to create the conditions in the Product backlog item and add the tasks as well.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you want to create the work items in batch (PBI and the attached tasks) when applying a PBI work item template.

It's not supported if you mean to crate a work item template with predefined linked tasks (or other work item type), we can only set the value of the fields in the template, cannot link or create other child/related work items within the template. Please refer to [Use templates to add and update work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) for details.

The only way I can think of is that writing a script to call the REST API ([Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)) to create the PBI and other tasks, then link the tasks to that PBI.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I implemented already some of the options and will explore your suggestion.

Comment: @Yaron Have you resolved the issue by the suggestion? Any update?

Comment: As far as I researched the option of creating a template for PBI with pre-populated sub tasks is not available. We decided to use plain test as acceptance criteria within the PBI template, and the users will create sub-tasks when needed.

Comment: @Yaron Yeah, template for PBI with pre-populated sub tasks is not supported, we can only create the sub-tasks manually, or just call REST API to create them in a script as I mentioned in the answer.